# Use JPA to query a jsonb type column

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have a postgresql table with a columnm of type jsonb.

```
create table zmab_ana_tessuti
(
    id_ana_tessuti        serial
        constraint zmab_ana_tessuti_pk
            primary key,
    composizione          jsonb,
);
```

I mapped this table with the following Entity

```
@Table(name="zmab_ana_tessuti")
@Entity
public class AnaTessuto {
    @Id
    public Long idAnaTessuti;

    @ColumnTransformer(
            write = "?::jsonb"
    )
    public ObjectNode composizione;
}
```

I need to create a specification in JPA what implements a query on the jsonb column like

```
Specification<AnaTessuto> spec = (root, query, builder) ->
     builder.isNotNull(root.get("composizione-->'CO'"));
```

this is the result I want to achieve

```
select *
from zmab_ana_tessuti where composizione->>'CO' is not null;
```

Is it possible to use Springboot SPA Specifications to create such a where condition?